# Using javascript on ID to link to other page without event onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website in wordpress, so I can't add the event onclick on the html code. But I can add css and javascript.

I've added an ID to the element that I want clickable. And added this javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('theID').onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = 'link';
}
```

I can't understand why it is not working. Are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: In theory, the code will work. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hws3q1gp/ . Perhaps you are running this code before the element exists in your page (and therefore getElementById would fail) - you must include the script _after_ the target element (or at least ensure it's within a "DomContentLoaded" event handler). Do you get any console errors when you use this code? The other issue is that only one onclick handler can be assigned to an object at a time. So if any other script is trying to do the same on this ID, it might overwrite it. Maybe use addEventListener instead, it doesn't have that issue

Comment: You might also consider https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Can you at least show the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not you use JQuery?
If you can use JQuery, bind the event like this,

```
$("#theID").click(function(){
  location.href="link";
});
```

Comment: @Chimelin it's worth noting that this is functionally equivalent to using addEventListener as I mentioned in the comments above. So if this is all you changed, then it seems likely that the issue was multiple onclick definitions overriding each other, as I had speculated. I mention this because it's always a good idea not just to know that something worked, but also to understand _why_ it worked, then we can avoid similar problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

If what @ADyson is saying true, you need to wait for your webpage to load and then call the onclick functionality to redirect to different webpage:

```js
 window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("redirectThis").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
    }; }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <button id="redirectThis">Click this to direct it</button>
  </div>
```